# How do I list files with a specific extension(.json,.txt,etc) in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have tried this code but when I try to run it, as I go to that portion the cmd window just closes. It is supposed to list the files with .json extension in that directory. Probably something wrong with the code?

```
 :TrackPrevious

 cd /D "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\"
 echo.> "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\fileslist.txt"
 for %%G IN ('dir /a-d /b /s') do 
 echo %%~nxg > fileslist.txt  
 )

 for /F "delims=" %%G IN (fileslist.txt) do (
set DeviceList=%%G
 )

 echo %Devicelist%`
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish here, but what about `dir /B /S /A:-D "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\*.json"`?

Answer (score 1):

#### Probably something wrong with the code?

There are many errors in your code.

```
echo.> "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\fileslist.txt"
```

The above `fileslist.txt` is not the same `fileslist.txt` as used in the rest of the batch file as it is created in a different directory. This line can be removed from the batch file as it is not needed.

```
for %%G IN ('dir /a-d /b /s') do
```

The above is missing a `/f` after `for` and a `(` at the end of the line.

```
echo %%~nxg > fileslist.txt
```

The above has `g` instead of `G` and `>` instead of `>>`

```
echo %Devicelist%`
```

The above has a trailing `` ` `` which probably shouldn't be there.

It probably should also be inside the second `for` loop, in which case delayed expansion should be used together with `!Devicelist!`.

I've fixed the errors (see below), but it still requires further work.

It is unclear what you are actually trying to achieve and your broken batch file doesn't match the title of your question.

**test.cmd:**

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:TrackPrevious

cd /D "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\"
rem echo.> "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\fileslist.txt"

for /f %%G IN ('dir /a-d /b /s') do (
  echo %%~nxG >> fileslist.txt 
  )

for /F "delims=" %%G IN (fileslist.txt) do (
  set DeviceList=%%G
  echo !Devicelist!
 )

endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.
- [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) - Redirection operators.

Comment: You fixed his code, but it's still going to list all of the files in the directory and not just the .json ones.

Comment: @SomethingDark That's why I said "it still requires further work.

It is unclear what you are actually trying to achieve and your broken batch file doesn't match the title of your question."

Comment: @SomethingDark Also his first `for` loop just fills in `filelist.txt` and the second `for` loop reads it out again. So both loops are unnecessary and it's really not clear what the OP actually wants.

Comment: Admittedly, I had just woken up and was reading the question on my phone. Your comment is right in the middle of a very long answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution by setting your extensions for searching for example : if you set like that :

`SET "EXT=txt json vbs hta bat url"` so, you can store all files names with those specific extensions `(txt json vbs hta bat url ...)` in an array variables on the fly without creating a filelist.txt and you can explore the search results with windows explorer like that :

```
@ECHO OFF
Title Scan a folder and store all files names in an array variables
SET "ROOT=%userprofile%\Desktop\"
SET "EXT=txt json vbs hta bat url"
SET "Count=0"
Set "LogFile=%~dp0%~n0.txt"
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
REM Iterates throw the files on this current folder and its subfolders.
REM And Populate the array with existent files in this folder and its subfolders
For %%a in (%EXT%) Do ( 
    Call :Scanning "*.%%a" & timeout /T 2 /Nobreak>nul
    FOR /f "delims=" %%f IN ('dir /b /s "%ROOT%\*.%%a"') DO (
        Call :Scanning "%%f"
        SET /a "Count+=1"
        set "list[!Count!]=%%~nxf"
        set "listpath[!Count!]=%%~dpFf"
    )
)
::***************************************************************
:Display_Results
cls & color 0B
echo wscript.echo Len("%ROOT%"^) + 20 >"%tmp%\length.vbs"
for /f %%a in ('Cscript /nologo "%tmp%\length.vbs"') do ( set "cols=%%a")
If %cols% LSS 50 set /a cols=%cols% + 15
set /a lines=%Count% + 10
Mode con cols=%cols% lines=%lines%
ECHO  **********************************************************
ECHO  Folder:"%ROOT%"
ECHO  **********************************************************
If Exist "%LogFile%" Del "%LogFile%"
rem Display array elements and save results into the LogFile
for /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do (
    echo [%%i] : !list[%%i]!
    echo [%%i] : !list[%%i]! -- "!listpath[%%i]!" >> "%LogFile%"     
)

( ECHO. & ECHO Total of [%EXT%] files(s^) : %Count% file(s^) )>> "%LogFile%"
ECHO(
ECHO Total of [%EXT%] files(s) : %Count% file(s)
echo(
echo    Type the number of file did you want to explore ?
set /p "Input="
For /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) Do (
    If "%INPUT%" EQU "%%i" (
        Call :Explorer "!listpath[%%i]!"
    )
)   
Goto:Display_Results
::**************************************************************
:Scanning <file>
mode con cols=75 lines=3
Cls & Color 0E
echo(
echo Scanning for "%~1" ...
goto :eof
::*************************************************************
:Explorer <file>
explorer.exe /e,/select,"%~1"
Goto :EOF
::*************************************************************
```