# How to Find a Specific text in a Specific line of text in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I was trying to do this in batch. I know how you can get a specific string in a specific line. But my question is: Is there a way to get only specified string in that line? The code i used to get the specific line is :

```
:64BIT
@echo on
cd /D "C:\"
dir curl_for_64bit.exe /S > "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\reply.txt"
cd /D "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\"
for /F "skip=3 delims=" %%G in (reply.txt) do (
set "var=%%G"
)
```

The output that was stored in reply.txt was:

```
 Volume in drive C has no label.
Volume Serial Number is 901C-31D8

 Directory of C:\Users\onlYUs\Documents\jezreel\64BIT

08/24/2016  05:26 PM         2,140,672 curl_for_64bit.exe
           1 File(s)      2,140,672 bytes

 Total Files Listed:
           1 File(s)      2,140,672 bytes
           0 Dir(s)  126,741,708,800 bytes free
```

What I want is to get the line "Directory of C:\Users..." and remove the string "Directory of"

The reason why I want to get the path only is: as soon as the location of curl_for_64bit.exe, the reply will be stored in the reply.txt and get the line with C:\Users... so that the batch can immediately change to that directory.

Comment: Édit your question and add your code

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I mean post the code that you have tried until now !

Comment: Explain more your aim with code and examples because it is unclear for us to help you as you expected ! 

You asked it here ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360642/how-do-i-find-a-specific-file-name-in-batch-and-change-to-that-directoryand no person can reply to you until now because is still unclear !

Comment: Please read this ==> [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you at least test and reply to this ? ==> [How do I list files with a specific extension(.json,.txt,etc) in batch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314253/how-do-i-list-files-with-a-specific-extension-json-txt-etc-in-batch?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: To get the *line* of text containing a certain string use `find` or `findstr`; to get a certain *portion* of that line parse its output by a `for /F` loop: `for /F "tokens=2*" %%I in ('dir /S "curl_for_64bit.exe" ^| findstr /B /C:" Directory of "') do echo %%J`. However, I am quite sure you are trying all this to achieve the same as in your other question ([How do I find a Specific File Name in Batch and change to that directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39360642)), what I just provided a much easier [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39365152) for...